# How to record only media sound while recording Android screen

Tags: android, kotlin, mediarecorder

I would like to know how to record only the media sound when recording the Android screen. It is said that only media sound can be recorded using REMOTE_SUBMIX, but REMOTE_SUBMIX is not possible in the source. Because of this, I think this will not work, but if you look at the Google Store, there are many recordings of screen recording and media audio at the same time. What the hell are you doing?

I'm not sure how. please tell me